# React Native Flipper plugin not installing OSX

Tags: macos, react-native, plugins, flipper

I have react native Flipper installed. I went into plugin manager, install plugins, searched for redux-debugger, installed 1.2.2, reloaded, found the plugin in disabled, and accidentally clicked the bin icon and deleted it. Then I went back to install it again, and now every time, it installs, and when I reload, it is gone. If I look in ~/.flipper/installed-plugins, after I install it, the directory flipper-plugin-redux-debugger exists, until I reload, and that directory disappears.

Steps I have taken to fix: removed ~/.flipper and started again. It did not help. Why would the plugin install only once, and never again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I finally fixed it by doing Flipper: Settings (gear icon) -> "Reset all local storage based state" and then restarted Flipper. Now the plugin shows as installed.

Comment: After searching for an answer for about 3 days, this finally worked. Thanks! 